# How to run ionic/angular app with cordova on android amulator?

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on an ionic/angular app with cordova for android. I am trying to run the app on android emulator with live reload.
So I am using the command-
"Ionic cordova run android -l". In the command line it says run successful  but in the emulator when app is launched it gives an application error that says Err_connection_refused http://localhost:8101/.

When I tried to emulate on android the app was running successfully but I want to be ab able to run the app with live reload on emulator as I also want to view some console logs as well as logcat logs too.

Comment: This has been answered many many times. You need to search before asking a duplicate question....

Answer (score 0):

Try to use or overwrite those tags in `configs.xml`:

```
<content src="index.html" />
<allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8100" />
```